# heroku pipeline CI fails on rails application with mysql db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, heroku

I have a pipeline on Heroku that connected to a rails application and each ENV(development, staging, production, test) connected to its own DB schema.
the problem is when I test a couple branches parallelly at the same time the test fails because all of those tested connected to a single schema. One test result is affecting another one and causes test goes fail.
this is one of example I got on running 2 tests at the same time but it's fine when they run one by one so I believe one test result is affecting to another one.
My question is what is the best practice of doing parallel unit testing without crashing?

```
Failures:
  1) User is valid with valid attributes
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { create :user }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1 does not exist: ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Mysql2::Error:
     #   Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
     #   ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @MaviDomates I updated it. My question is what is the best practice of doing parallel unit testing without crashing?

Comment: Are you assigning the same user properties and writing to the same DB in parallel? In that case it's easy :)